# Jenkins Pipeline doesn't clone private Git repository to local workspace on virtual machine

Tags: github, jenkins

I'm having a problem with running a Jenkins Pipeline script from SCM. Jenkins doesn't clone the code from my private Github repository to Jenkins' private workspace [(Console output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD3Nk.png). I have a private repository on Github, from which I get the code that the pipeline has to execute. On the virtual machine on which Jenkins is installed I've executed the following commands to generate a SSH-keypair:

```
sudo su jenkins
ssh-keygen
```

I've added the public key to my **Github repository** under "Deploy keys" and the private key in Jenkins under Manage Jenkins -> Manage Credentials -> Global credentials -> Add Credentials as SSH Username with private key (with "jenkins" as Username). This worked for about a week. Last monday (30/05/2022) it suddenly stopped cloning the code from my private Github repository into the local workspace of the vm, which is /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/"pipeline name". After that I've tried the following:

- Revert a snapshot of the VM that was made after the installation of Ubuntu server 20.04.4 and    install Java 11 and Jenkins freshly
- Remove my Github account and make a new one
- Make a new repository
- Generate new SSH-keypairs
- Use HTTPS and a Github personal access token

After this I tried to generate a new ssh-keypair using this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my_email"
```

I've added the public key to my **Github profile** under "SSH and GPG keys" and the private key in Jenkins under Manage Jenkins -> Manage Credentials -> Global credentials -> Add Credentials as SSH Username with private key (with my email adress of my Github profile as Username).

When I navigate to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/"pipeline name", a Git Clone <-SSH url-> **does** work and my pipeline **runs without failing**. However, this manual action is not preferred.